# setTimeout time value greater than max value

Tags: javascript, html

how to handel setTimeout() function in java script with value greater than max value.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="funCall()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function funCall()
    {
        setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3147483647);
    }
   </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's `parseInt` supposed to do on a number?

Comment: So you want to wait 36 days and then do something?

Comment: How do you think there is a "max value"? Does your browser throw an exception on that?

Comment: @Dve Those are millisecondes.

Comment: That is 36429.2088773 days...

Comment: Yes I want call a function after 36 to 40 days.

Comment: @11684 No, that is ~36.5 days.

Comment: If I was very confident in my browser I would simply store a time in a variable and use `setTimeout` with smaller delays until the end...

Comment: Yes, I just realized... @VisioN

Comment: Is that intended to run in a browser ?

Comment: Yes. If i exceed the max value then the inline function execute immediately

Comment: @ChittaranjanSethi , as soon as you close the page or refresh, the javascript is gone. This can only work if you keep your computer 'on' for 36 days.

Comment: Do you really need to set a timeout for over a month from now??

Comment: @ChittaranjanSethi Maybe you got something wrong... You ***really*** need to leave your browser open for 40 days. No shutdown, no refresh, no judgement day.

Comment: Yes I want this code for a web based application.

Comment: @Chittaranjan: Not in my browser. Which one are you using?

Comment: I suspect the number is actually not intended to be 36.4 days, because it happens to be exactly 1e9 more than `(1 << 31) - 1`

Comment: This code will be run in a server.

Comment: Ah, Node.js? I bet they provide something better for that.

Comment: ah, not a Windows server, then...  In any event, this sounds like an "XY problem".

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It's always better to test twice... Take 2 times.

Comment: @ChittaranjanSethi What for a server ? Why don't you store the upcoming date for example and then check if now - date > xx days at each visit ?

Comment: I guess the question can be consciously closed as *"Not a real question"*.

Comment: I want to open pop up when my server will be down for maintenance.

Comment: 9 years later, this is still a legitimate question and should not have been closed. On a recent Chrome version 98.0.4758.102, for example, the maximum timeout value is 2147483647 milliseconds, or 2^31 - 1. As @Kaeros noted, this corresponds to the maximum positive value of a 32-bit signed integer. Rephrasing the question: "How to schedule a callback in JavaScript when the delay you need is greater than the maximum delay supported by setTimeout?" The answers already posted work fine to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
(function () {

    var timers = {};
    var id = 0;
    var maxT = 1000;  // can go up to (1 << 30)

    window.setLongTimeout = function (f, t) {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
        var now = (Date.now && Date.now()) || +(new Date);
        var end = now + t;
        var myid = ++id;

        (function loop() {
            var now = (Date.now && Date.now()) || +(new Date);
            var delta = end - now;
            if (delta <= 0) {
                delete timers[myid];
                f.apply(null, args);
            } else {
                timers[myid] = window.setTimeout(loop, Math.min(maxT, delta));
            }
        })();

        return id;
    };

    window.clearLongTimeout = function (myid) {
        window.clearTimeout(timers[myid]);
        delete timers[myid];
    };

})();
```

It fires a timeout periodically until such time as the originally specified time (which is not constrained to 32 bits) has elapsed.

Expect to get precision errors if you try to use it for more than `2 ^ 52` milliseconds ;-)

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/zGdn5/

Comment: Nice, but I still don't see what's wrong with the original code. It didn't fail for me.

Comment: @Bergi I expect it's interpreter specific.

Comment: @Bergi if you mean `setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3147483647);` it fails for me (chromium/ubuntu) : the alert is immediately shown. Probably because some engineers thought there was no point in supporting such delays.

Comment: @dystroy it fires immediately for me too, Chrome 24 on MacOS X

Comment: +1 for a nice and clean implementation. Too bad it would be stupid to use it (an addition, probably not worth your time) could be a localStorage persistence to make it more resistant.

Comment: @dystroy I don't think I'd use localStorage for this - as far as I'm concerned a page refresh should put you back at a clean slate.

Comment: @Alnitak I'm not sure we can constructively build from such a weird and fuzzy specification anyway...

Comment: @dystroy FWIW, I was half-tempted to modify this so that it actually overrides the built-in `setTimeout` function ;-)

Comment: Replacing the standard function by a (marginally) slower one just for an insane use case ? Well...

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout uses a 32 bit signed int to store the delay, so every number above this does not work and the code is executed immediately.

You could create a setTimeout with the max value and them call another setTimeout inside your function with the max value.

Comment: You have a lot of faith in your browser.

Comment: So `2^32 = 4294967296` is the maximum? That cannot be right, `4294967296 > 3147483647`...

Comment: https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=nl&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=2%5E32&oq=2%5E32&gs_l=hp.3..0l3j0i30.24939.171873.0.172009.19.17.2.0.0.0.121.1040.16j1.17.0...0.0...1c.1.2.hp.z9s9LKjYg3Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42261806,d.d2k&fp=c4d73c87dfe13ad7&ion=1&biw=1680&bih=929

Comment: Which browser does that?

Comment: No. This I have already tried.

Comment: @ChittaranjanSethi And what was the problem ?

Comment: Actually the [HTML5 IDL](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) says that the timeout is a `long`.

Comment: @dystroy the inline function executed in less than 1 sec

Comment: @ChittaranjanSethi Then there are two options: 1) an overflow, 2) you made a typo.

Comment: @kaeros Of course! Undownvoted!